# C# List and Memory

Tags: c#, memory

I'm new in C# and wondering if list1 is really removed from memory after list1 = null;

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "carrot",
    "fox",
    "explorer"
};
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add(list1[0]);
list2.Add(list1[1]);
list2.Add(list1[2]);

list1 = null;
```

This code is only for documentation, in my real case list1 object is really big, and I need to removed it from memory, and continu only with list2 that is a fraction of the original list1.

I assume list1[0] and list2[0] are referencing the same object in memory until I update list2[0] with a new value... Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

There are several questions. Let me try to answer them seperately:

1. Is list1 removed from memory when the reference to list1 is set to null?

   No, the list is removed from memory when the garbage collector is cleaning up the heap the next time. When this cleanup will take place is up to the garbage collector.
2. Are list1 and list2 referenceing the same objects?

   Yes, they are.

So in conclusion this means that you do not have to deal with memory management. This is done by the garbage collector. And the garbage collector is smart enough to know when it has to collect orphaned objects. So dont try to do it better than the GC does. In nearly every case it is getting worse.

Comment: memory retention is my biggest concern as list1 is really big. I guess I need then to clone the objects nedded in list2 to be sure that list1 is no more referenced and removed propertly by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Chris: No, you don't have to clone the objects. As far as your objects are string, they will not be cloneable at all. Under the hood they will still point to the same object. And besides that cloning the objects will not influence the garbage collector in any way. Don't think about memory. The GC knows when it should be cleaned up. I suggest you to read some Garbage Collector HowTos as already mentioned here in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

C# is not C/C++ - there is no direct memory management.

The list object will no longer be accessible (assuming that's all the code that uses it), so will not be accessible from the object root. This will allow the GC to mark it for collection.

The memory will be reclaimed once the GC collects.

Comment: But you can call GC.Collect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx. It might reclaim memory.

Comment: @AmiramKorach - It might. It might not. And it is bad practice to call it directly. Regardless, that's not what the question asked.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: Yes, but it's not a good idea to tell people who are only now learning C# "you can collect memory like this". Their lack of experience will lead to severe abuse. Good advice is not only about what is said, but also what is left unsaid.

Comment: Agree. There are very few reasons every to call GC.Collect, if any in most cases.  Chris, if fact you don't even need to care about setting your instance of list to null, as once it goes out of scope and is not longer in use, it will be available for garbage collection, which will free up that memory once it needs to.

Comment: thanks for all these answers. I don't want to call GC.Collect necessary. My concern is only memory retention for nothing. As the code is running on a server I want to clean it much I can.

Comment: @Chris The GC will take care of your memory. WHen the GC thinks that a cleanup makes sense, it will do a cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that list will be deleted. When you assign null it is eligible for garbage collection and whenever GC is invoked it collects it.

**From MSDN:**

Once the object is eligible for destruction, at some unspecified later time the destructor (if any) for the object is run. Unless overridden by explicit calls, the destructor for the object is run once only.

Once the destructor for an object is run, if that object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, including the running of destructors, the object is considered inaccessible and the object becomes eligible for collection.

Finally, at some time after the object becomes eligible for collection, the garbage collector frees the memory associated with that object.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider different issues:

- You have to consider how List class is defined, see
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/6sh2ey19.aspx (navigate
  through interface hierarchy)
- You have also to consider if the base type T of List can be
  disposed freeing all the resources
- C# is a garbage collector based
- Please, read also these articles:

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At the point when a garbage collection occurs, its memory will be reclaimed.

See [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx) for further details. ( Conditions for a Garbage Collection
 )

Answer (score 1):

Keeping references to null wouldn't delete the memory but it will eventually get garbage collected.

GC Myth: setting an object's reference to null will force the GC to collect it right away.

GC Truth: setting an object's reference to null will sometimes allow the GC to collect it sooner.

You can read more about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2004/12/01/273144.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the list1 and list2 are pointing to different locations.
Just change the value of `list1[1] = "Something different"` just before the line `list1 = null` and check in immediate window the value of `list2[1]` will still remain "fox".

However if you use

```
List<string> list2 = list1;
```

then list2[1] will be "Something different".

Note: In both the cases making *list1 = null* will not have effect on list2 and it will still contain values.